# Some questions on Minkowski's functional

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm reading [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional) on Minkowski's functional. They state that if the set K used in defining Minkowski's functional p<sub>K</sub> is convex then p<sub>K</sub> is sub-additive. They argue as follows:

> Suppose for the moment that p<sub>K</sub>(x) = p<sub>K</sub>(y) = r. Then for all ε > 0, we have x, y ∈ (r + ε) K =  K' . The assumption that K is convex means K' is also. Therefore ½ x + ½ y is in  K' . By definition of the Minkowski functional p<sub>K</sub>, one has
>
> $p_K\left( \frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{2} y\right) \le r + \epsilon = \frac{1}{2} p_K(x) + \frac{1}{2} p_K(y) + \epsilon . $
>
> But the left hand side is ½ p<sub>K</sub>(x + y), i.e. the above becomes
>
> $p_K(x + y) \le  p_K(x) + p_K(y) + \epsilon, \quad \mbox{for all} \quad \epsilon > 0.$
>   This is the desired inequality. The general case p<sub>K</sub>(x) > p<sub>K</sub>(y) is obtained after the obvious modification.

**0)** Let us examine this argument. When they say that "for all ε > 0, we have x, y ∈ (r + ε) K =  K' " is the only place they use convexity, isn't that right? Furthermore  in saying that $p_K\left( \frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{2} y\right)=$½ p<sub>K</sub>(x + y), they use homogeneity of the functional, don't they?

**1)** So how does subadditivity follow from convexity alone?

**2)** Furthermore, if we define the functional to be infinity whenever we take an infimum over the empty set, how does our set being absorbent guarantee finiteness?

**3)** Finally if K is balanced how come ($\lambda x \in  K) \Leftrightarrow (x \in \frac{1}{|\lambda|} K$)?
How come $\inf \left\{r > 0:  x \in r K \right\} 
= \inf \left\{ \frac{1}{ | \lambda | }r > 0:  x \in \frac{1}{|\lambda|}r K \right\}$? Do we need K to be balanced for the last equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** They need convexity for $x,y \in K' \Rightarrow \frac12 x + \frac12y \in K'$.

**2)** Absorbent means that for each $x$, there exists $\alpha$ such that $x \in \alpha \, K$. Hence, you get finiteness.

**3)** Balanced means, that $K = -K$. From this, you obtain the equivalence. For the last inequality, you simply replace $r$ by $r/|\lambda|$. No balancedness needed.

Comment: Oh, but then how come "for all ε > 0, we have x, y ∈ (r + ε) K," when K is convex. What if K has holes in it, (K is not balanced)? Also p K (1 2  x+1 2  y)= ½ pK(x + y) uses homogeneity, which follow from the set being balanced, isn't that right?

Comment: You are right. For the first implication, you need convexity. For the second one, you need positive homogeneity ($p_K(\alpha \, x) = \alpha \, p_K(x)$), which just follows from the definition, without further assumptions.